# Why Force.Com Migration Tool Does NOT deploy CustomMetadata Records?

Tags: change-set, migration-tool, force.com-ide, custom-metadata

For the first time we started using Custom Metadata types to store our
Custom Settings data.

We created a new custom metadta type and created some metadata records for the object

> Eg: Metadata object name : CountryMetadata and Created 5 metadata detail
>   rows with 5 countries

I tried to debug the issue with followings;

**With Force.com migration tool** However when we try to deploy the metadata object to another Org with force.com migration tool
this doesn't deploy the metadata detail records to the target Org.

**With Force.com IDE** : secondly I used the froce.com IDE and pushed metadata records to the target Org and it worked fine (This is a temporary alternative and not what I really want)

**With Changesets** After all of these attempts, I tried deploy changes through change sets, though this also
doesn't have an option to deploy metadata records to the target Org.

***My question is*** how could we deploy CustomMetadata Records with Force.Com Migration Tool?

More Info:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>AccountCriteriaBasedSharingRule</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>AccountOwnerSharingRule</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>AnalyticSnapshot</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexClass</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexComponent</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexPage</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexTrigger</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApprovalProcess</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>AuthProvider</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CallCenter</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CampaignCriteriaBasedSharingRule</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CampaignOwnerSharingRule</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CaseCriteriaBasedSharingRule</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CaseOwnerSharingRule</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Community</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ConnectedApp</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ContactCriteriaBasedSharingRule</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ContactOwnerSharingRule</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomApplication</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomLabels</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Custom​Metadata</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <members>Account</members>
        <members>AccountContactRole</members>
        <members>Activity</members>
        <members>Asset</members>
        <members>Campaign</members>
        <members>CampaignMember</members>
        <members>Case</members>
        <members>CaseContactRole</members>
        <members>Contact</members>
        <members>ContentVersion</members>
        <members>Contract</members>
        <members>ContractContactRole</members>
        <members>Document</members>
        <members>Event</members>
        <members>Lead</members>
        <members>Opportunity</members>
        <members>OpportunityCompetitor</members>
        <members>OpportunityContactRole</members>
        <members>OpportunityLineItem</members>
        <members>OpportunityTeamMember</members>
        <members>PartnerRole</members>
        <members>PersonAccount</members>
        <members>Product2</members>
        <members>Site</members>
        <members>Solution</members>
        <members>Task</members>
        <members>User</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomObjectOwnerSharingRule</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomObjectTranslation</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomPageWebLink</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomSite</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomTab</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>DataCategoryGroup</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>AllDocuments</members>
        <name>Document</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>ADMIN_Only</members>
        <name>EmailTemplate</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Flow</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Group</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>HomePageComponent</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>HomePageLayout</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Layout</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>LeadCriteriaBasedSharingRule</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>LeadOwnerSharingRule</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Letterhead</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>OpportunityCriteriaBasedSharingRule</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>OpportunityOwnerSharingRule</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>PermissionSet</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Portal</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>PostTemplate</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Profile</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Queue</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>QuickAction</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ReportType</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Role</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>SamlSsoConfig</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>StaticResource</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <members>ts2__Application__c</members>
        <name>Workflow</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Settings</name>
    </types>
    <version>35.0</version>
</Package>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your package xml version in your metadata file? Also share metadata you used to deploy via migration tool..what's the migration tool version..

Comment: Kindly note all has to be 35 to get it working..

Comment: Also i find it in changesets from their document .

Comment: I'm using version 35, and updated the post with package.xml

Comment: Have you double checked that each record is actually in your metadata?  You should have some files named Object_Name.Record_Master_Label.md in the customMetadata directory.

Comment: Yes @Nick I have all the metadata for MetadataType Records

Comment: I used latest force.com migration tool .Make sure to use very latest..

Comment: I found whats wrong with my Change sets here are the things to add: 
1>The custom metadata type object itself (__mdt)       
2>Fields of the custom meta data type you created     
3>Layout of the custom meta data type     
4>Lastly the custom metadata records (you can see the     customMetadataType object's name listed in the "Component Type" dropdown )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is some invisible character in documentation between small 'm' and capitalised 'M' in `CustomMetadata` and in the closing `</members>` tag (&​#8203; Unicode Character 'ZERO WIDTH SPACE' (U+200B) http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm ), that is why this code

```
<types>
    <members>*</​members>
    <name>Custom​Metadata</name>
</types>
```

doesn't work while this would work

```
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>CustomMetadata</name>
</types>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @patlatus! I've Implemented a small groovy script to remove the invisible character. I'm posting it here as an answer so it could be useful for someone.

```
println "Removes the invisible characters in CustomMetadata"
def customMetadata = ant.fileScanner {
  fileset(dir: '${target.dir}') {
    include(name: 'CustomMetadata/*.md')
  }
}

for (m in customMetadata) {
   m.eachLine { def line ->
    sb.append( line.replace('\u200B', '') )
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've resolved this for your change set, but your package.xml is still missing plenty of __mdt components.  (CustomObject, CustomField, etc)

These docs might help you (or future readers) better understand how to structure a package.xml using custom metadata:

[Metadata API v35 docs from SFDC](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_custommetadatatypes.htm)